# Auto-select project in Grails Command dialog based on Project Explorer selection in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, grails, ggts

Is there a setting in eclipse GGTS/STS that pre-selects the project in Grails Command dialog menu, based on the selected project in Project Explorer?

I've prepared this stunning visual to promote my question :-D

[image]

Comment: That's how it's always worked for me - it autoselects the current project; I'm pretty sure it's not configurable

Comment: so it works for you, not for me, and it's not configurable? just my luck :-)

Comment: If using the keyboard is an option, it seems like Ctrl+Alt+Shift+G will set the project based on the currently selected file.

Comment: @MattZ you're right, the keyboard command works, just not the toolbar icon